# method that accepts two integers, and prints the sequence of numbers between them

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, integer

I am a beginner of java and I really appreciate if anybody can help me with this program.
I am working on this now, and I believe I need to use scanner, int, loop, and if/else statement. The description of the program is below:

Write a method called printRange that accepts two integers as arguments and prints the sequence of numbers between the two arguments, enclosed in square brackets. Print an increasing sequence if the first argument is smaller than the second; otherwise, print a decreasing sequence. If the two numbers are the same, that number should be printed between square brackets. Here are some sample calls to printRange:

printRange(2, 7);

printRange(19, 11);

printRange(5, 5);

The output produced should be the following:

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11]

[5]

I have written some of it, and I don't know what to do in the printRange method. I believe I need to int something so that I can make for loops work. I also don't know how to make the numbers to be in [] with , and space. It would be so helpful if you could help my code work...

import java.util.*;  // for Scanner

public class PrintRange

{ //begin class PrintRange

```
public static void main(String[] args)

  { //begin main method

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This program prints the sequence of numbers between the two numbers that you give");

    //obtain values
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers (x,y)");
    System.out.print("Number x: ");
    int x = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number y: ");
    int y = console.nextInt();      

    int sequence;
    sequence = printRange(x,y);

    System.out.println("The sequence of your number is " + sequence);

  } //end main method

public static int printRange(int x, int y)
  { //begin printRange method   
    //this method accepts two parameters and return an integer
int 
    if (x > y)
    { //begin if statement
      //x is larger than y
        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
        {//begin for loop i
        System.out.print("[" + i + "]");
        range = range + i;
        }//end for loop i

    } //end if method

    else if (x < y)
    { //begin else if method
      //x is smaller than y
        for (int j = x; j >= y; j--)
        {//begin for loop j
        System.out.print("[" + j + "]");
        range = range + j;
        }//end for loop j
    } //end else if method

    else if (x == y)
    { //begin else if method
      //x is equal to y
        System.out.print(x);
        range = range + x;
    } //end else if method
return range;
  } //end printRange method
```

} //end class PrintRange

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Right now it seems like a homework dump and that simply won't do.

Comment: "Write a method" , who is going to write?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning this, I won't code the answer for you. I'll give you hints.

1.import java.util.Scanner if you haven't already.

2.for loop is: `for(int i= 0;i<parameter.length();i++)`

3.Look up .substring() here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

4.Scanner works like this:

```
System.out.println("HERE you put what you ask the user for input");
int input = input.nextInt(); //this stores the user's input in var input
```

5.Good luck! I suggest you run a `for` loop and use the substring on the counter i.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
public static void printRange( int x, int y) {
  if(y  > x) {
    for (int  j = x; j <= y; j++) {
        int i = 1*j + (x - 1);
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
  } 
  else if (x > y){
    for (int j = x; j>= y; j--) {
        int i = -1*y + (x -y +1) * 2  +1;
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
  } 
  else {
    System.out.print(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printRange(int int1, int int2) { 
if (int1<=int2){
    for (int i = int1; i <=int2; i++) { 
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
} else {
    for (int i = int1; i >=int2; i--) { 
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
}
```